# XAML Textblock cannot be centered

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a PopUp element in my XAML, inside this I have a Grid with a TextBlock inside.

The problem is now, that the text and the grid cannot be centered with Horizontal and Vertical Allignment...

**XAML**:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup" Height="30px" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Grid Height="30px" 
            Background="Green" 
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Popup}">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       Text="Änderungen wurden übernommen">
            </TextBlock>
      </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Preview in Visual Studio (which looks exactly like what I want to do):
[image]
Actual Result: 
[image]
The TextBox inside the green PopUp is not centered as you can see. And I dont know why, maybe I´m missing something, but everything looks fine for me.

Comment: You cannot trust `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Popup}`, if the width of the Popup gets updated, the width of Grid won't be affected.

Comment: Hello again my friend :D 
How can I change the width then to the parent control?

Comment: First, what exactly are you trying to show here? Just a message box floating on the top?

Comment: Yep, it is just like a information for the user, when he clicks the button (with fade in, fade out animation)

Comment: But `Popup` doesn't support animations out of the box. `Flyout`'s animation is half-baked. Are you implementing your own? You can try subscribing SizeChanged event and manually update the width, but I'd create my own control for this.

Comment: I´m using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations for the animations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually subscribe to `SizeChanged` of your `Popup` like this -

```
Popup.SizeChanged += (s,e) => PopupGrid.Width = Popup.ActualWidth;
```

---

### Update

I normally would create a `UserControl` popup that exposes a `MessageText` property so I can pass in dynamic text, and another `IsOpen` flag to toggle its visibility. I also disable it from hit testing and allow it to dismiss itself after a few seconds.

Hiding and showing should be done via `Storyboard`s which are encapsulated inside the control.

In the end, this `MessageControl` should look like this -

```
<local:MessageControl IsOpened="{x:Bind MyToggle.IsOn, Mode=OneWay}" Message="Die Änderung wurde übernommen!" />
```

I have included a sample project [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/MessagePopupRepo) for your reference, and this is how it looks like -

[image]

Comment: nvm, I just used my own Grid, which I animated. And it works perfectly without any event handlers or something.. but thank you though

Comment: exactly, just a Grid, with a TextBlock inside :)

Comment: U can edit your answer, so that I can mark it as a solution if you want..

Comment: I will have to update with something more than that. Wait for it. :)

Comment: np, take your time :)

Comment: I did it like this:

Comment: <Grid Background="LimeGreen" Height="40px" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="GridPopup" Opacity="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Die Änderung wurde übernommen!"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>